# Why toasts fired on a coroutine are displayed even when the coroutine is cancelled?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, android-toast

I have an application that displays **a lot** of Toasts, as a result Toasts are displayed long after the application went on background.

In order to cancel all Toasts when the application is in background, I have implemented a custom class to wrap the calls to `Toast.makeText` into a single call done on a coroutine. My idea was that when the `onPause` method of an activity is fired then I could call `CoroutineContext.cancel()` to cancel all coroutine. By doing so I hoped that all Toast would have been canceled.

```kotlin
class CustomToast  {
    val job  = Job()
    val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    fun showSuspendToast(context: Context, msg: String) {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            Toast.makeText(context, "FROM CustomTEST | $msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    fun cancelToastCoroutines() {
        coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
    }
}
```

Obviously it does not work.

Why does it not work? Where is the error in my reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Toast.makeText` is non-blocking. Toasts are queued by the system. Therefore, all the `Toast.makeText` are long finished when you get `onPause`. Cancelling the coroutine does nothing because the coroutine isn't doing anything when you cancel it.

You should add a `Log` after `Toast.makeText`, that would visualize to you when the toast are scheduled.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Or queue the toast on app side and call `Toast.makeText` with delay simulating actual toast delay. Anyway, if one gets so many toasts or snacks that they have to be queued it means that the app needs different method of communicating events.

Comment: the toast are instantly sent to the system, the coroutine has then nothing to do and is finished, at some point later the Toast is displayed, period. thanks @Agent_L

Comment: But @Tenfour04, there is a public function `Toast#cancel()`: _Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet._ It is also said in doc: _You do not normally have to call this._ which does not mean that it can´t be called. Right? Anyway, Snackbars are definitively to be considered

Comment: @eqtèöck, you're right, I was remembering wrong. Unfortunately, callbacks were only added in SDK 30. If your minSdkVersion is at least 30, you could use the callbacks to create a suspending version of the `show` function that allows the coroutine strategy to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `minSdkVersion` is probably lower than 30, but just in case it is 30 or higher, you could create a function that shows the toast in a suspending cancellable way so that your strategy could work. This uses Toast callbacks, which were added in SDK 30.

```
suspend fun Toast.showCancellable() = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    val callback = object: Toast.Callback {
        override fun onToastShown() {}
        
        override fun onToastHidden() {
            removeCallback(this)
            continuation.resume(Unit) 
        }
    }
    addCallback(callback)
    show()
    invokeOnCancellation { 
        removeCallback(callback)
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04, my minSdk is 33. I will give a try